# How to add class on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Probably a simple solution. I would like to expand an embedded video underneath the "Watch the video" when it is clicked. Pretty straight forward, however I can't get this code to add the "expanded" class on click to the video__player div for the life of me. Any help here is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Code:

```js
$(".video").click(function() {
  $(".video__player").addClass("expanded");
});
```

```css
.video__player {
  display: none;
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 560px;
  max-height: 315px;
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: auto;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.expanded {
  height: 45vw !important;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video__container animated fadeInDownShort slow">
  <a class="h6 video clickable">Watch the video <img class="play-btn" src=""></a>
</div>
<div class="video__player">
  <br><br>
  <iframe src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/egge6gur/), the problem is something else.

Comment: have you wrapped your click handler  with a DOM ready handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, as the comment says, you might not have wrapped it in a $(document).ready(function() {}); handler. Two, your allowFullScreen hasn't set a value. Unset, it's default is false. If you want to allow it fullscreen, set it to true. 
Posting your full code through a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [repl.it](https://repl.it) would help as well, as it could be something else.

In the stackoverflow interpreter, your code seems to be working fine. Perhaps it's something with whatever interpreter you're using?

Comment: Thanks, it was the $(document).ready(function() {}); that was missing.

Comment: However, the expansion of the div isn't taking the 0.5s duration that I set with CSS. How would I go about animating the expansion?

Comment: @SpencerM. Try using 500, instead of .5s. 500 is set as 500 milliseconds, or half a second. If not, try using .animate or .css, as you can set the properties while also setting the amount of time to "fast", "slow", or a set time in milliseconds.